Why can't I find any records of my Great x2 Grandfathers travelling to New Zealand or Australia?
Background
I am going to provide a little bit of background in this one question, in case it is
relevant.

My Great x2 Grandfather (George Scammell) was born in 1856 in Semley, Dorset.Birth certificate ordered.
He got married to Martha Coke in 1878 in Motcombe, Dorset. Marriage certificate received.
My Great x2 Grandmother, Martha admitted to Roundway Hospital in Devizes in 1912. I had a few questions about her medical records on here (eg: Deciphering Lunacy Asylum case notes about escaping through a window).
She died in 1917.
Their youngest daughter (Ethel Nellie Scammell)  married an Australian (August Edward Eichler) in 1918. He was a supplier and his father was also a retail trader (according to their marriage certificate).
We discussed a bit about her travels to New Zealand and Australia here (Finding details about an immigration from England to New Zealand / Australia). I have confirm that she lived at the same address 53 Sandown Road, Springvale from at-least 1954 - 1980.
She died in 1984 but I have not purchased her death record.
My Great x2 Grandfather George Scammell died in Murrayville in 1931. Discussed on here yesterday (Transcribing text on Death Record).

Question
Why can't I find any records about his travelling to New Zealand or Australia?
According to his death record, his song-in-law August stated:

Born England; Victoria 2 years; New Zealand 8 years;

So he clearly moved to these countries. I have found some possible electoral roll entries for him in New Zealand and Australia. But, why can't I find any documentation of his travelling to these countries?
Now, I know there there are several entries for a George Scammel in 1978 but this is not the same man. That man was travelling with his wife Bertha at the time with their young baby. I am told that their baby sadly died on the journey. So this is not my Great x2 Grandfather.

Side Point
I stumbled upon a book (I don't have access to unfortunately) that documents Edith Nellie Scammell husband emigration etc:

The nuggets found in the Ancestry hints have at-least filled in about her husbands movements (and correlates with information on their marriage certificate). I see that you can purchase excepts of the book but I have no idea what page range I would need to cover their lives.
The above said, I don't think it would bring me any closer to finding out about George Scammel movements as regards living overseas.

What were the birth years and locations for children of George and Martha? If they start to be in Australia, then that could narrow your search. Dying in 1931 with "Victoria 2 years; New Zealand 8 years" (presumably his last, perhaps in reverse order) suggests he landed in New Zealand or Victoria in about 1921.  Was he in England's 1921 Census?  What is the earliest record that you have of him in New Zealand?  What is the earliest record that you have of him in Victoria?  Do you have records of him in any other Australian states?

@PolyGeo George / Martha had already had all their children here in the UK. As mentioned, Martha died in 1917 and it was after this date that George went to New Zealand / Australia. I have records of him on electoral roles but that is not really enough to go on. That is just a name. I see a NZ electoral in 1922. But not sure if it is him. He did not show up on 1921 census when I did all the searching for my family some time back.

It sounds like your hypothesis may be that he was in New Zealand from about the second half of 1921 (to miss the census) until going to Victoria in about 1929 (Great Depression so perhaps seeking work opportunities) and dying there in 1931.

@PolyGeo Yes. And since he had an illness, he would be nearby his daughter / son-in-law.

I am going to take your question very literally for a moment and give you some suggestions on how to get organized before you make your next searches.
Once upon a time, I was looking for a family whose first child was born in Canada. I wanted records that would show them going from Canada to the USA.  I quickly learned (the hard way) that border crossing records from Canada to the US weren't kept when they came to the USA, so I was never going to find a tidy passenger list with all the members of the family on it.  I might still find a record someday, if someone mentioned their trip in a letter or diary, but it won't be the record I was expecting to find.
Step 1: review everything you already have
Make a table (choose the tool that works best for you) with each family member in their own column. Use the rows for years. Map out where everyone is at the times you know about. Bear in mind that when the children are born, unless they were adopted, you can infer the mother was present but the father need not be. You want to establish the possible date ranges for your 2g-grandfather's movements around the county and between countries.
Step 2: List the sources you have by type and evaluate them
Make sure you've understood the records you already have.  For death certificates, who is the informant? How likely is it that the informant has personal knowledge of each bit of information, or is it something they would have had passed down to them as family knowledge?
For low-content sources like electoral rolls, treat them as belonging to a different person and ask: How can I find out more about the person who lived at 123 xyz street? Can you trace the dwelling and get more clues that way?
Step 3: List the databases you searched, where you did not find him, and evaluate them
Widen your view and look at the big picture.  Do you know the date ranges of the databases you've searched? Do you know how many records in the database have no names associated with them because of bad indexing?
Step 4: Expand your range of sources
Consult guides such as the FamilySearch Research Wiki and think about record sets that you might have missed.  If the records you want to find weren't mandatory, or weren't retained (such as the census), or were never created, what other sources might have the same information?  In the USA, there were no departure records for one period I was rearching, but I was able to find information about the family's travels in historical newspapers. You don't mention if you have looked in newspapers via Trove  or PapersPast, both of which are free, or if you have checked the GLAM Name Indexes for other records from the GLAM sector.
Debugging why you could not find a record about an event is a multi-step process. It requires you to look at the big picture: to learn about the law (to find out what record sets were mandatory), to research record sets, to evaluate databases, to improve your own search skills.
Resources:

Some Genealogy Records Have No Names by Crista Cowan, on Ancesty's YouTube channel
FamilySearch Wiki: Australia Record Finder
FamilySearch Wiki: New Zealand Record Finder

